# How to upload files to the server in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, uploading

i am willing to upload the file to the server without using any gem. Following is what i have tried:

the following is the function that i have created in modal:

```
def self.file_upload(uploaded_file)
    puts uploaded_file
    file = Tempfile.new(uploaded_file, 'http://52.41.99.60/GEMWebservices/Image')

    returning File.open(file.path, 'w') do |f|
      f.write file.read
      f.close
    end
  end
```

I have used the above function in create acrion as follows:

```
@file_upload = User.file_upload(params[:uploaded_file])
```

But i get the following error:

```
unexpected prefix: #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa0909fbe00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/tt/d903z3v94sbgr8yymqxn_m0m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160829-27648-gzgzt8.jpeg>, @original_filename="kaka.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\"kaka.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
```

Can any one help me out? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet :

```
def file_upload(file)
  file_path = '/GEMWebservices/Image/'+file.original_filename
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'GEMWebservices','Image',file.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(file.read)
  end
  file_path
end
```

In action:

```
@file_upload = file_upload(params[:uploaded_file])
```